# How will this code compile

Tags: c++, function-pointers, inline-functions

Suppose we have below code:

```
inline void DoSome()
{
    cout << "do some" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    void (*pDoSome)() = DoSome;

    DoSome(); // one
    pDoSome(); // two
}
```

For above code we have three possible scenarios:

1. one will be inlined, two won't
2. one and two will be inlined
3. one and two won't be inlined (because we took the address of function)

Now I want know which of the above scenarios is true?

Comment: They could all be true, depending on what the compiler chooses to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`inline` is a hint to the compiler, but it is not an obligation. It is up to the compiler to decide if a function declared as `inline` will actually be inlined and thus any of the two calls may or may not be inlined.

Answer (score 6):

All scenarios are possible, because the compiler may optimise as it wants. The only option to see what happened is to look in the assembler output.